# Spark Submit Succeeded but Airflow Bash Operator Fail with Exit Code 127

Tags: bash, scala, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, airflow

I am using airflow bash operator to run a spark-submit job. The spark job takes some parameters. The last parameter is a string that can be converted to a nested array by using "," and "|" split. 
sample submit command:

```
spark-submit --verbose --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster --queue some_queue job.jar <dt> <s3bucket> <xx:yyy,zzz|ss:aaa,bbb>
```

The strange thing is when the spark job finishes, it outputs:

```
final status: SUCCEEDED
Command exited with return code 127
ERROR - Bash command failed
```

Has anyone run into the same problem and how do I resolve it? I have many other airflow jobs that use bash operator to run spark submit command, never had an issue like this.

Comment: My assumption is that one of the character in your command (most likely the `|`) is taken as a bash character. So there are effectively two bash commands being executed and piped together, the second of which fails because the syntax is obviously wrong. Just my hypothesis.

Comment: So you can either escape that character, or use the SparkSubmitOperator instead of the BashOperator, see https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/master/airflow/contrib/operators/spark_submit_operator.py

Comment: It is not the bash command itself, but most likely airflow. When I run the same bash command directly, it works fine. But when it was wrapped in airflow, it throws an error.

Comment: Any reason for not using the SparkSubmitOperator instead?

Comment: we are still on an old version

Comment: I didn't solve the problem, worked around it by hard coding that parameter, since it is not expected to change frequently. It appears the variable passed by Airflow Variables may contain some weird and not visible syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Escape the pipe in the last parameter like the following:

```
spark-submit --verbose --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster --queue some_queue job.jar <dt> <s3bucket> <xx:yyy,zzz\|ss:aaa,bbb>
```

OR

```
spark-submit --verbose --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster --queue some_queue job.jar <dt> <s3bucket> "<xx:yyy,zzz|ss:aaa,bbb>"
```

Comment: I had my suspicion on the pipe too, but it was not the pipe. I used ";" as the separator before and had quotes around that parameter, but the job would just fail in the case. I always got emr file system consistency error with the last element, but it was apparently not emrfs consistency issue, because it always happens to the last element.

For example, if I had "xx:yyy,zzz;ss:aaa,bbb", the for loop that processes bbb file would throw consistency error, but if I pass "xx:yyy,zzz:ss:bbb,aaa", I would get the same error on aaa.

Comment: Also, all of these work fine on its own but fails when run using airflow bash operator.